# JQuery Dialog - NOT OPENING Second Time

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

There are several posts on StackOverflow on the subject but none of the answers helped me.
I am using the DataList control that is populated by a SELECT through a DataAdapter.
A concept is recommended that only one instance of the dialog must be open but could not apply this method

The structure of the html is:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList" runat="server">
         <ItemStyle />
         <ItemTemplate>
             <a href="" class="link"/></a>
             <div class = "dialog" id="dynamicID" style="display:none">
             </ div>
         </ ItemTemplate>
     </ asp: DataList>
```

The jQuery code I'm using is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $ (function () {
         $ (". link. ") click (function () {
             var id = '#' + ($ (this). siblings ('. dialog'). attr ('id'));
             $ (id). dialog ({
                 AutoOpen: false,
                 closeOnEscape: true,
                 resizable: false,
                 draggable: false,
                 modal: true,
                 width: 800,
                 height: 600,
                 overlay: {backgroundColor: "# 000", opacity: 0.5},
                 top: 20,
                 show: 'fade',
                 hide: 'fade',
                 buttons: {
                     "Close": function () {
                         $ (id). dialog ('close');
                     }
                 }
             });
             $ (id). dialog ('open');
         });
     });
</ script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Dialog not opening a second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700495/jquery-ui-dialog-not-opening-a-second-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine this **HTML**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dataList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <p>
                Result: <strong>
                    <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %></strong></p>
            <a href="#" class="link" data-open="dialog_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" />Click
            To Open</a>
            <div class="dialog" id="dialog_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">
                <h2>
                    This is the text inside the dialog #
                    <%# Container.ItemIndex %>.</h2>
                <p>
                    &nbsp;
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

with this **javascript**

```
$(function () {

    // create dialogs
    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(id).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    // hook up the click event
    $(".link").bind("click", function () {
        // console.log($(this).parent());
        // open the dialog
        var dialogId = $(this).attr("data-open");
        $("#" + dialogId).dialog("open");

        return false;
    });

});
```

works lovely.

> **Working example** [can be found here](http://balexandre.com/Stackoverflow/6279021/)

**What is wrong** with your approach?

you are creating the dialog's inside a method, and this should be created inside the `$(document).ready()` so, everytime you click, it creates a dialog, but... it already exists and screws up everything.

When working with dialogs:

- First you create them using `.dialog()`
- You just need to use `.dialog('open')` to make that dialog visible
- And use  `.dialog('close')` to hide that dialog

by default jQuery UI CSS will hive the dialogs automatically (`display:none;`) so you don't need to do anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually just destroying the dialog on close will fix the issue.

```
$( "#dialogbox" ).dialog({ 
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When dialog has displayed it fall out from the markup flow. So when you call `var id = '#' + ($ (this).siblings('.dialog').attr('id'));` you don't get anything. You can add dialog's id to array first time it opens and then if `$(this).siblings ('.dialog')` result is empty you may get dialog element id from array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var registeredDialogs = [];

        function registerDialog(link, dialogDiv) {
            var linkId = $(link).attr("id");
            if (!registeredDialogs[linkId])
                registeredDialogs[linkId] = dialogDiv;
        }

        function getDialog(link) {
            var linkId = $(link).attr("id");
            return this.registeredDialogs[linkId];
        }

        $(function () {
            $(".link").click(function () {

                var dialogDiv = $(this).siblings('.dialog');
                if (dialogDiv.length !== 0) {
                    registerDialog(link, dialogDiv);
                }
                else {
                    dialogDiv = this.getDialog(link);
                }

                dialogDiv.dialog({
                    AutoOpen: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600,
                    overlay: { backgroundColor: "# 000", opacity: 0.5 },
                    top: 20,
                    show: 'fade',
                    hide: 'fade',
                    buttons: {
                        "Close": function () {
                            $(id).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(id).dialog('open');
            });
        });
    </script>
```