# jQuery dialog box is not opening 2nd time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700495/jquery-ui-dialog-not-opening-a-second-time) which basically has the same issue I have. But their solution is not working for me.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // create the loading window and set autoOpen to false
    $("#loadingScreen").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,    // set this to false so we can manually open it
        dialogClass: "loadingScreenWindow",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 460,
        minHeight: 50, 
        modal: true,
        buttons: {},
        resizable: false,
        open: function() {
            // scrollbar fix for IE
            $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        },
        close: function() {
            // reset overflow
            $('body').css('overflow','auto');
        }
    }); // end of dialog 

});


function waitingDialog(waiting) {
    $("#loadingScreen").html(waiting.message && '' != waiting.message ? waiting.message : 'Bekleyin...');
    $("#loadingScreen").dialog('option', 'title', waiting.title && '' != waiting.title ? waiting.title : 'Yükleniyor');
    $("#loadingScreen").dialog('open');
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dawb9/1/

Answer (score 0):

use `$("#loadingScreen").dialog('option' ....` just once, and then call `$("#loadingScreen").dialog('open')` as many times as you need

Comment: can change options as often as needed before an open